# Do pointer receiver intended to fail in deep generic sturctures?

Tags: go

1st snippet (https://go.dev/play/p/-M1Z9V3KBjx)
Pointer receiver call from normal function.

```
package main


import "fmt"

type C struct {
    GUID string
}

func (c *C) guid() string {
    return c.GUID
}

type I interface {
    C
}
type P interface {
    cc()
}

func constructor[T I]() T {
    return T{}
}
func main() {
    b := constructor[C]()
    x := &b

    fmt.Println("<" + x.guid() + ">")
}
```

2nd snippet (https://go.dev/play/p/mkLZ1pCwBu_X)
Pointer receiver call from method of generic struct

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

type C struct {
    GUID string
}

func (c *C) guid() string {
    return c.GUID
}

type I interface {
    C
}
type E[T I] struct {
    Body T
}

func constructor[T I]() E[T] {
    return E[T]{}
}

func (e E[T]) guid() string {
    x := &e.Body
    return x.guid()
}
func main() {
    e := constructor[C]()
    fmt.Printf("%+v", e)
    fmt.Println(e.guid())
}
```

First one works, second one fails (type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)

Comment: All your T are C so why bother with type parameters at all? If you want all your T to have a guid method: add that to I, not the single type C.

Answer (score 0):

- Because you are using a pointer receiver in `guid()` method, you need to define the `C` struct as a **pointer** in the `I` interface.
- Generic methods that are related to the given Struct should be defined in the `I` interface.
- Two other Structs and A parameter to the `constructor` function were added to get a clear understanding.
- You don't need to parse type to the `constructor` function. (*Type inference*)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"


type A struct {
    GUID string
}

func (a *A) guid() string {
    return a.GUID
}

type B struct {
    GUID string
}

func (b *B) guid() string {
    return b.GUID
}


type C struct {
    GUID string
}

func (c *C) guid() string {
    return c.GUID
}

type I interface {
    *A | *B | *C
    guid() string
}

type E[T I] struct {
    Body T
}

func constructor[T I](arg T) E[T] {
    return E[T]{
  Body: arg,
 }
}

func (e E[T]) guid() string {
    x := e.Body
    return x.guid()
}

func main() {
    
    a := constructor(&A{GUID: "<guid of A>"})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)
    fmt.Println(a.guid())

    b := constructor(&B{GUID: "<guid of B>"})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    fmt.Println(b.guid())

    c := constructor(&C{GUID: "<guid of C>"})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    fmt.Println(c.guid())
}
```